# Using GraphHighlight interactively

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks, dynamic

I want to build a small GUI, where the user can select either a single edge or a single node of a graph. I got to this point:

```
selection = {};

Dynamic[Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
   3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1},
  PlotLabel -> selection,
  VertexShapeFunction -> (EventHandler[
      Disk[#1, .1], {"MouseClicked" :> (selection = {#2})}] &),
  EdgeShapeFunction -> (EventHandler[
      Arrow[#1, .1], {"MouseClicked" :> (selection = {#2})}] &),
  GraphHighlight -> selection,
  GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick",
  ImageSize -> 200
  ]]
```

Which gives the following (note that I already highlighted an edge by clicking on it for clarity):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now if I try to click on one of the **nodes**, the dynamic visualization breaks, giving back the unevaluated result:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note, that the `GraphHighlight` and `PlotLabel` options correctly registered the click, as the selected node is on their right hand sides. Any idea what the difference is in this context between edges and nodes? The two clicking functionality are meant to be identical.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason why it fails is because of `GraphHighlight`. If you're highlighting a single vertex, then it expects an atom and not a list. In other words, it needs to be something like `GraphicsHighlight -> 1` instead of `GraphicsHighlight -> {1}`. However, this is not the case for edges, where even a single edge can be supplied wrapped in a list.

So the culprit here is the `{#2}` in `VertexShapeFunction -> (...)`, and all you need to do to fix it is remove the `{}`. The following code works.

```
DynamicModule[{selection = {}},
 Dynamic[Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
    3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1}, PlotLabel -> selection,
   VertexShapeFunction -> (EventHandler[Disk[#1, .1], 
       "MouseClicked" :> (selection = #2;)] &),
   EdgeShapeFunction -> (EventHandler[Arrow[#1, .1], 
       "MouseClicked" :> (selection = #2;)] &), 
   GraphHighlight -> selection, GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick", 
   ImageSize -> 200]]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: And I wonder why is that so. It definitely smells like someone forgot to add the `func[single_?AtomQ]:=func[{single}]` piece of code...